# Making API call from child components based on screen size

Tags: angular, api

I want to render a child component in my parent component when the screen size is less than or equals to 600px.

**Parent Component HTML:**

```
<div class="small-screen">
      <app-child-component> </app-child-component>
 </div>
```

**Parent Component SCSS**

```
.small-screen {
      @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
             display: none;
     }                  
  }
```

And in my ChildComponent's ngOnInit I have made an API call to get some data from the server.
But in my parent component when the screen size is greater than 600px (or in any size),
the child component's API is getting called, though my child component is not visible when the screen size is greater than 600px. I want to call the API in my child component only when it's visible in my parent component. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**display: none** css only hides the element but it is still in DOM. You need to get width of parent component and use it to show/hide child component using ***ngIf**

In parent.component.ts

```
public innerWidth: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

In parent.component.html

```
<app-child-component *ngIf="innerWidth > 600"> </app-child-component>
```

If you want to update innerwidth value on resize. Add this in parent component.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't in showing/hiding the child component. Please read the last section carefully.